# How to trace the loading process of C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, libvlc

I'm developing a small qt app that uses libvlc libraries to provide video playback functionality, but the problem I met is that it needs much time to load all the libraries at *first* time playback is launched.

So there's the question - is there any ability to trace the process of loading libraries? (It's better to show some kind of "Loading..." window to user.)

Comment: How do you load your libraries? If  they are linked during compilation  I think there is no way to do this (it will be loaded automatically by OS runtime linker); but if you do this through QtPlugins there may be a way through QPluginLoader.

Comment: I link them dynamically, but thought there's a way to inject in some method that loads it and "make some magik" showing a loading window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than monitoring the loading, you can simply trigger loading those libraries during program start.  This will make it invisible to your users, because people expect a program to take a second or two to load anyway.

An easy way to do this might be to call `libvlc_new()` when your program is starting up.

Comment: Wow, extremely great solution, but I won't make it at start, but exactly in the moment of loading, because this function is blocking (hope debugger doesn't lie).